# vagrant up timing out on Windows 10

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to boot up a vagrant instance but it seems to hang at the  `default:     SSH auth method: private key` part no matter what I do. I'm new to vagrant so it's entirely possible that there's something I haven't done but should have.

System info:

Windows 10 build 10586.420

Vagrant 1.8.4

VirtualBox 5.0.22 r108108

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

I had a look around for similar issues and people have suggested making sure Hyper-V is disabled (which it is) and enabling the virtualbox GUI to see if there are any other errors that aren't being put in the command line.

When I open the virtualbox GUI, I see a username/password prompt (see below):
[image: VirtualBox screenshot]

I've tried entering the default vagrant username/passwords and these work but the vagrant up script still hangs and eventually crashes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.